# utf-8 encoded persian text in anchor tag not properly shown by IE8

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a project which is in Persian language. On the admin side of this project some Persian text in anchor tag and button tag displays wrong although I use `charset=utf-8`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">; 
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl"> 
    <head> 
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> 
        <meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"> 
        <title>osCommerce</title>
```

Comment: My code is       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots">
<title>osCommerce</title>

Comment: Please put your code into the question!

Comment: Is your file really stored as UTF-8, (the file format, not the HTML declaration)? You can check your page with this [W3-checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) to find problems with the encoding.

Comment: yes I have stored file in utf-8 format

Comment: Can you provide a link to this page, with a description how it should look like? Is it a problem with IE only, or do other browsers show the same result?

Comment: It has a problem only on IE8.

Comment: Then open the page in IE and press `F12` to show the developer tools. Here you can see the browser mode, it should **not** be in the Quirksmode. If it is in the quirksmode you should make your HTML page valid HTML, see this [W3-validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: It shows in Standard mode,it displays some content right but content in button and anchor tag are not right

Comment: Please create a minimal example page and paste a link to it, otherwise it is very difficult to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if your html is compatible with xhml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
...
</head>
```

if you used Netbeans or eclipse or any IDE check if your project is using the utf-8 file encoding.

Comment: yes I have stored file in utf-8 format,it displays some content right but content in button and anchor tag are not right

Comment: Check your database setting as well it need to be utf-8 encoded as well

Answer (score 1):

apart from this `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">`
you should also save the `yourpage.php` script file in `utf-8 format`.

Comment: it displays some content right but content in button and anchor tag are not right

Comment: yes,font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;

Comment: please remove the font  and check.